# Best practice to show custom fields on dynpro?

Tags: user-interface, abap, user-experience, dynpro

I am assigned to implement new custom fields. The possible entries have to be selected from a value table. The value table holds the key and a explaning text. The dynpro is build like that:

```
Input for new field (zzfield) | Output-only field for explaining text. (zzfield_text)
```

What I want my dynpro to do:

- a) Show text in output field based on entered key
- b) Update text after ENTER/SAVE from user
- c) Update text directly after a new key has been selected from the value table

My current solution is this:

```
" in the dynpro
PROCESS BEFORE OUTPUT.
  MODULE GET_ZZFIELD_TEXT.

" in the module
DATA: zzfield_text TYPE string.
SELECT SINGLE text
  FROM value_table
  INTO zzfield_text
  WHERE zzfield = mara-zzfield.
```

This works well for the cases a) and b) I have listed above. However, beeing in a PBO, it does not work for case c). My colleage suggested to use something like this:

```
" in the dynpro
PROCESS AFTER INPUT.
  field: zzfield MODULE get_zzfield_text_pai ON REQUEST.
```

I can not duplicate my code in the module get_zzfield_text_pai, because the of the DATA declaration of zzfield_text. It is reported to be unknown in the PAI (besides it is already defined in the PBO module) but it is also reported to be duplicated if I declare it again in the PAI. Further, I dont know how to implement new global fields into my function group. Using another include creates again issues of that zzfield_text beeing unknown.

In general, I am not happy about my solution and would be very thankfull for each suggestion about how to code this feature.

Comment: It looks like you haven't even received the most basic training on ABAP development. I would strongly recommend you take the courses BC400/BC401 and/or get a good introductory book.

Comment: I am new to ABAP yes. This is the reason I ask this kind of questions here. Those BC4XX documents are very badly made, tbh.

Comment: I don't think this is a question that is suitable for the Q&A format of Stack Overflow. You most probably need the courses (not only the course materials, but several days to weeks of hands-on training) if you don't even know about the most basic modularization techniques.